# ¿Porque la tarea programada no ejecuta la aplicación?

Tags: c#

EL siguiente código es parte de un programa un poco mas extenso que lo que hace es abrir el chrome, desde una aplicación de consola, con una ruta para la descarga de un archivo

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe",url);
```

Cuando realizo la ejecución del .exe directamente con doble click abre correctamente el chrome y descarga el archivo, pero si lo dejo por tarea programada no se abre el chrome y por ende no descarga nada.

¿Hace falta alguna configuración en la tarea o por código para que se ejecuta de forma normal en la tarea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cuando la ejecutas manualmente te sale el UAC de windows?, el usuario con la cual la ejecutas es administrador?

Comment: Podrías sacar una imagen de como esta programada la tarea? Porque el problema puede ser desde esa parte

Comment: @zerocool , el usuario con el que ejecuto es administrador 100% seguro

Comment: Verifica el registro de errores de windows, si es un tema de permisos te lo indicará, tienes que ir a herramientas administrativas -> visor de eventos (o buscas en el inicio visor de eventos) allí buscas los errores en registro de windows -> aplicación. Colocanos que te indica windows al ejecutar la tarea. Además coloca el desencadenador de la misma (trigger).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deberias usar la opcion `Run only when user is logged on` para que esta pueda interactuar con el desktop

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: una consulta, por que la otra opción no funcionaría?, acabo de hacer lo que me indicaste y funciono pero me queda esa duda.

Comment: Al no haber un usuario autenticado no se tiene acceso a la pantalla para interactuar con esta, solo podrias ejecutar procesos que ejecuten sin interaccion, eso es lo que indica esa opcion al configurar la task

Comment: Y si la pc esta bloqueada pero con una sesión iniciada, la ejecución de la tarea no se ve afectada?

Comment: mmm, entiendo que la session del usuario aun esta activa, pero no se si afectara la interaccion con el desktop, en principio deberia funcionar pero seria cuestion de probarlo para asegurarlo

Comment: lo que pasa es que esa tarea se ejecuta en un servidor al cual me conecto por escritorio remoto, entonces me quedaba la duda si cuando cerrará la conexión al servidor esto podría afectar la tarea, pero parece que no, ya lo deje a modo de prueba y ejecuto de forma normal, gracias por la ayuda.